# Error when trying to kill processes -- "kill: pid: arguments must be process or job IDs"

Tags: linux, ssh, sphinx, kill

I'm trying to kill Sphinx on my server so that I can restart it. I tried using this command to find the PID:

```
ps ax | grep "searchd"
```

Which printed out this:

```
 1483 ?        S     00:00 /usr/local/bin/searchd --config /path/to/sphinx.conf
 1484 ?        Sl    20:51 /usr/local/bin/searchd --config /path/to/sphinx.conf
 1523 ?        S      0:00 /usr/local/bin/searchd --config /path/to/another/sphinx.conf
 1524 ?        Sl    20:35 /usr/local/bin/searchd --config /path/to/another/sphinx.conf
14174 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep searchd
```

I'm confused why there are duplicate entries and can't figure out what the `S` or `Sl` columns mean, but I tried this:

```
kill pid 1483
kill pid 1484
```

But that outputted this error:

```
-bash: kill: pid: arguments must be process or job IDs
```

When I list the processes again, it looks like it did kill the processes (I ran the kill command for the first two), but the error makes me wonder what I did wrong?

Comment: Off-topic; belongs on [su]

Comment: They might be zombie processes. Don't know..

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process

Comment: My theory is that the kernel didn't validate them as valid process ids when `kill` tried to send message them yet the kernel recognizing that they were zombies, killed them which doesn't become apparent to `kill` who just reports back that they didn't exist. Just a theory :)

Comment: Why are you not using `searchd --stop` ?

Comment: @barryhunter Two reasons: 1) I didn't know it existed :-) and 2) it looks like that stops all `searchd` processes, as opposed to just for one website?

Comment: It only stops the approriate one(s), if you have multiple 'instances' you should pass the config file too `searchd --stop --config /path/to/sphinx.conf` - it uses the pid file (from the config) to identify the right master process. The child processes are automatically shutdown by the master.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's

```
kill 1483
kill 1484
```

When you entered

```
kill pid 1483
```

What you said in effect was

> Please kill the processes with number 'pid' and 1483.

The reference to `pid` in the message

```
-bash: kill: pid: arguments must be process or job IDs
```

is telling you the string 'pid' was not a valid process ID

Comment: How were they not valid PIDs since they were shown with the `ps ax` command? And where did `1486` come from?

Comment: Thanks, I had the same problem and this solved it for me.